# How to connect to another web site and retrieve data using my php page text box?

Tags: php, curl

I have a Textbox in a php page. If i enter a value in it, have to redirect to another website and search for the keyword i have entered in it. how to do this in php?

Comment: If you're redirecting the user to another website, then your site is completely out of the picture and you cannot "search" that other site for them.

Answer (score 0):

If the site you want to search is something like google you can use their API so with just a few changes in your html code, your form will search the web for the text entered. See [this](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_can_i_add_a_google_search_box_to_my_web_site.html) for example.

In the case the site you want to search has no built in tool or such functionality, you are basically hoping that the site is using the get method for searching, so you can build php location [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), after you process the entered information.

So if someone enters the term "find this" in your search box, you will have to do something like

```
header("Location: site_im_searching_in/blablabla?search=find+this")
```

Though the second method is anything but recomended because any time the site changes the way they process URL's or the syntax they use, you will be left with a broken box.